# How to fix this mysql permission problem?

Tags: permissions, osx, mysql

I'm trying to get `rails dbconsole` to work (Rails 3.2.6). The problem is that when I run the command, I get:

```
gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:81:in `exec': Permission denied -
/usr/local/bin/mysql (Errno::EACCES)
```

I am using OS X Lion, and the usual way of running `mysql` at the command line works - it just doesn't work through `rails dbconsole`. The permissions on the `/usr/local/bin/mysql` are:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/mysql
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  16 Mar 13 20:27 /usr/local/bin/mysql -> /usr/local/mysql
```

The user I am calling these commands from is in the 'Admin' group (as evidenced in the Preferences -> Users dialog)

Any ideas on how to fix this? What could be the cause of `mysql` being able to run at the command line but not through another program (ruby/rails in this case).

And while I'm at this permissions problem, could you point me to a decent article/book/method that will help me to understand the permissions system and help troubleshoot such problems in future?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/local/mysql`? The permissions on a symlink mean precious little.

Comment: Exactly the same permissions, but the group is `wheel` (the group for `usr/local/bin/mysql` is `admin` - as mentioned in the question)

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ld /usr /usr/local /usr/local/mysql`, of `type mysql`, and of `head -n1 gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Conjecture: `mysql` doesn't run `/usr/local/bin/mysql`, but a `mysql` executable at some other location in `$PATH`. It is unusual to have `/usr/local/mysql` be an executable file: I would expect it to be a directory, if it exists at all. Run

```
type mysql
```

to see what `mysql` really runs, and if necessary, correct the `/usr/local/bin/mysql` symbolic link to point to the right place.

You can see what is really behind the symbolic link by adding the `-L` option to `ls` (and `-d`, in case it turns out to be a directory):

```
ls -lLd /usr/local/bin/mysql
```